# Setting up an XMLHttpRequest for Predict the Sky API

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

[The API in question is this one](http://predictthesky.org/developers.html). I'm having trouble understanding the required format for XMLHttpRequest urls. I think it's like this:

```
var url = "http://api.predictthesky.org/?application/json?events/all?lat=0?lon=0";
```

But I'm getting this error: "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the host name api.predictthesky.org is not resolving. It has been gone since at least April (see forum posts like [this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9417286) or a tweet with #predictthesky).

You might try contacting one of the people associated with [their github repo](https://github.com/PredictTheSky) and see if they can resolve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, cheers, I just discovered this myself. Seems the API has been dead for awhile now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might not be in the link. Here is an explanation Mr. Glen Murphy, Design Director, Google Chrome.

> This is a pretty generic error that can be caused by a wide range of things. The most common cause can be fixed by unchecking 'automatically detect proxy settings' in your computer's network settings .(Chrome settings > Under the hood > Change proxy settings > LAN Settings).
>
> You can try manually entering a DNS server IP address in your computer's network settings, though that's a little more complicated.

You can checkout for more solutions here it it does not work

http://www.quora.com/How-can-I-fix-Error-105-net-ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED-The-server-could-not-be-found-on-Chrome